# How can I install a Canon Printer driver for mp495

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

Hi I'm a complete newbie to linux. I am running ubuntu 13.04. I am trying to install a canon pixma mp495 wireless printer. I have downloaded the canon printer driver from the canon european site but cannot install the driver. Can anybody help?

Comment: Try here: [http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/...](http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MP_series/PIXMA_MP495.aspx). Canon printers will work with Linux, but Brother or HP printers generally work better. You may also need to install CUPS (was/is known as Common Unix Printing System). Have you got it working with any other printers?

Comment: I presume that you have downloaded a tar.gz driver. You will probably have to extract the file, and look for any files called README or INSTALL. Open them in a text editor e.g. gedit, and see if there are any installtion instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Have the printer connected and on the same Wi-Fi network as the computer.

Go to System Settings, Printers, and add it. It should show up, and walk you through getting drivers and naming it.

In Linux, you rarely need to get software of any kind from Google searches. This is a common mistake of those coming from Windows. Programs come from repositories, and drivers are no different.

Comment: My system is Cinnamon 5.2.7 Linux Mint 20.3 Una base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal. I am trying to add a printer via system settings. At the device choice, I have _Generic CUPS-BRF_ and _Network printer_. At both options, I can find my _Canon MP495_. None of them run the printer. Which option is proper for WIFI?

Answer (score 2):

To install Canon Pixma mp495 printer driver for linux ubuntu 10.04 you need to add PPA below in your ubuntu system.

First open Terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then enter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon
```

For Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inameiname/stable
```

For Ubuntu 16.04 to 22.10:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
```

Then enter:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Disconnect your Canon MP495 from your computer or turn it off.
Then, install the Canon MP495 driver with the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mp490series
```

Comment: It fails for `Ubuntu 20.04 focal`. The result of `sudo add-apt-repository` is `Can't add a private package archive: "This PPA doesn't support focal"`

Answer (score 0):

i tried to install "sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mp490series" but got

"No-Aspire-V3-551 ~ # sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mp490series
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cnijfilter-mp490series"

should I look for another repo?

Comment: This is not an answer. I understand the rules for a required number of reputation to comment are a bit annoying, but to keep the site clean they need to be enforced. If this is different enough from the problem the OP has you can ask a new question and have it dealt with there.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded in scanning over USB using the Canon Pixma MP 495 printer/scanner on Kubuntu 16.04. I just followed this guide:

[SANE - Installing a scanner that isn't auto-detected - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SANE%20-%20Installing%20a%20scanner%20that%20isn't%20auto-detected)

Previously I had tried Warwizard's solution but that didn't seem to help the scanner. Now the Skanlite app still crashes but XSane Image works perfectly.